# IF statement to ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula in cell D2 in a Google Spreadsheet:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",B2-C2)
```

How do I apply that formula to the whole column D with ArrayFormula? Because ArrayFormula is the best solution, right?

Thanks

Comment: did you post this question twice?

Comment: No, they are slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the formula in the google sheets `Arrayformula()` function. Then change the reference from B2 to B2:B500 (or leave blank for open ended reference). Same for the second reference.

So `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="","",B2:B-C2:C))` should work. Note that I changed ISBLANK to X="" since the arrayformula is bound to find values in the entire array so it won't return blank.

--

Whether this is the best way I don't know. The benefit is that this grows with the dataset and avoids errors when you haven't filled the formula far enough down. However it can sometimes slow sheets down (I've heard but not experienced anything severe myself). If you're experiencing slow sheets I recommend [Ben Collin's blog](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/slow-google-sheets/) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks! Your formula works great but it turns out I gave the wrong formula as example. I want to subtract B3 from B2, B4 from B3, B5 from B4 and so on... What formula should I use then?

Comment: Good question, I guess you could try using closed ended references (i.e. B3:B501-B2:B500).

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: This works for me as an example `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B3:B8="","",B4:B9-B3:B8))`

Comment: You can also use MMULT to avoid using closed ended references so that you will not forget new lines.

Answer (score 1):

Whithout closed ended references

```
=mmult( arrayformula(1*(ROW(A2:A)<TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)+1))*(ROW(A2:A)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A))) -1*(ROW(A2:A)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)))*(ROW(A2:A)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)+1)) ) , A2:A)
```